# Reheating potentially unsafe canned goods unsafe?

Tags: food-safety, canning

I am into home brewing and one of the popular practices is for people to can wort - this is basically a sugary barley like tea- for growing yeast. A lot of people simply can wort in a pressure cooker or via normal steam canning methods, but after reading about the time variations necessary to can certain foods, and after failing to find a specific time recipe for wort even after emailing a government body asking for recommendations, I reached the conclusion that I did not need edible wort out of a can.

Instead I could just boil the wort once out of the can to kill any potential botulism toxin and still have the ability to portion large batches of wort into cans. The question is this: is there anything that won't be killed off in the boil that I need to worry about? After all, even though this is for yeast growth, I will end up drinking a small amount as it will end up in my beer.

Comment: Boiling doesn't get rid of botulism toxin. Don't do this.

Comment: To be clear: the Botulinum bacteria produces a toxin that can kill you. The bacteria itself isn't the toxin--the byproduct it produces (and leaves behind after the bacteria is killed) is the toxin.

Comment: https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/botulism - boiling will destroy the toxin